# knitr - change code indentation

Tags: r, knitr

I am working on a two-column (Rnw, latex) document where the width is at a premium. By default knitr indents the code blocks by 4 spaces. How can I reduce this default indentation?

Many thanks
David

Comment: I don't think it is possible ( not easy at list). How do you create your document? Do you use knit2html? using Rstudio?

Comment: I use ESS/emacs and knit2pdf (or similar)

Answer (score 3):

Either do not reformat the code (use the [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) `tidy=FALSE`) and manually indent by two spaces,

```
<<tidy=FALSE>>=
if (TRUE) {
  # code here
}
@
```

or set the R option `reindent.spaces` to a smaller value, e.g.

```
options(reindent.spaces = 2)
```

This option is passed to the [**formatR** package](https://github.com/yihui/formatR/wiki) to reindent your code, and **knitr** uses **formatR** to reformat your R code by default.